# Dell Latitude E5540 keyboard issue

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, dell

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Dell LATITUDE E5540 laptop, and I've the following problem: randomly I get one key repetition which stops when I press another key.
I think that this is my problem:

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19581331

But there is not a solution by dell yet. Has anyone encountered and solved the same problem? With another proprietary OS there are no problems with keyboard.

Thank you in advance!

Federico

Answer (score 1):

According to the reply to that forum thread [marked as “verified answer”](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19581331/20655550#20655550), this issue was fixed in a [BIOS update](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=N08MD&fileId=3384660450&osCode=W764&productCode=latitude-e5540-laptop&languageCode=EN&categoryId=BI).

#### How to update BIOS

> > - Download the `.exe` file downloaded from Dell's website and copy it into your `/boot/EFI` folder.
> > - Restarting your computer and run enter BIOS by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>.
> > - Select '**Flash BIOS upgrade**' and then select the `.exe` file that you downloaded from dell and wait for the update to be applied.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the BIOS update fixed the problem for me. In my case the A07 BIOS version was problematic, but the switch to [A14](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=GK5PG&fileId=3511063968&osCode=BIOSA&productCode=latitude-e5540-laptop&languageCode=en&categoryId=BI) fixed the issue.

As I am using Linux, the procedure for BIOS update was a bit more complicated than for Windows users, however a [Dell support page](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN171755/en) describes it very well.

Answer (score -1):

Change keyboard layout to "English UK" ... this worked for me

Comment: This may work but it isn't a very elegant solution. People get used to using one keyboard layout and having to learn the UK layout while also using the US layout on other computers would be troublesome.

Comment: Just butting in as I don't know if this will help, but `English, US (alternative International)` would be a good place to start if OP uses US QWERTY...  ;-)